# Deploying .NET 2.0 sp2

Tags: .net, deployment, .net-2.0

I would like to deploy the .NET Framework 2.0 sp2 redistrbutable (NetFx20SP2_x86.exe) with my app.

Do I need to uninstall 2.0 or 2.0 sp1 if they exist on the client machine first, or is it acceptable to simply install 2.0 sp2 over the top?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you ***don't*** have to manually uninstall. The msi you get from Microsoft will handle everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

New version upgrade (or install alongside) older versions. Why not experiment on a VM?